# magento 2 create categoy dropdown

Tags: magento2

Create Category drop down in which when we put category and put product name if product belongs to that category it will show product else not show any product
I created a PHTML to call  getCategories

**app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/frontend/template/notice.phtml**

```
$collection = $block->getCategories();
foreach ($collection as $categorycollection){
    print_r($categorycollection->getName());
}
```

**app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Block/notice.php**

```
public function getCategories() {
        $categoryFactory = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
        $categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
        print_r($categories);
        return $categories;
}
```